# How to Access Lists on a MS Teams Group via MS Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to fetch a list created on a MS Teams group but I couldn't find a way to do it via MS-Graph. Is there a way I can call lists or other info on a teams group with an api or rest calls?

Comment: Please refer this doc which explains how to retrieve lists and list properties using REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest. You can also refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0